# How to count number of element in json array

Tags: json, vbscript

I have a simple JSON array like this:

```
["123", "124", "321"]
```

The expected result should be `3`. How can I count the number of elements without using regular expressions and always working with a JSON object?

I tried using the following code:

```
Dim jsonStr, jsonArray, elementCount
jsonStr = "[""123"", ""124"", ""321""]"
Set jsonScriptControl = CreateObject("ScriptControl")
jsonScriptControl.Language = "JScript"
Set jsonArray = jsonScriptControl.Eval("(" + jsonStr + ")")
elementCount = jsonArray.Length
MsgBox "Number of elements: " & elementCount
```

However, I encountered an error message:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error: An ActiveX component cannot create an object: 'ScriptControl'.
```

Comment: This was a few days ago... [How to access JSON object returned from createObject("htmlfile") in VBS file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76640930)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decode/Encode JSON with VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153925/decode-encode-json-with-vbscript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access JSON object returned from createObject("htmlfile") in VBS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76640740/how-to-access-json-object-returned-from-createobjecthtmlfile-in-vbs-file)

Comment: If you are sure of json being an arry you can use 
 elementCount=ubound(split(jsonstr,","))+1

Comment: Follow-up would be appreciated. Did you resolve the issue some other way?

Answer (score 0):

`ScriptControl` is a 32 bit object. Therefore, your script must be run using a 32 bit scripting host:

`c:\windows\syswow64\wscript.exe My32bitScript.vbs`

Alternatively, for 64bit, use `htmlfile`:

```
jsonStr = "[""123"", ""124"", ""321""]"
Set html = wscript.CreateObject("htmlfile")
Set window = html.parentWindow
window.execScript "var json = " & jsonStr, "JScript"
Set jsonArray = window.json 
elementCount = jsonArray.Length
MsgBox "Number of elements: " & elementCount
```